# How to fix ubuntu 22.04 lts after changing default python version

Tags: boot, python

I changed my default python version from 3.7 to 3.10 with update-alternatives now my Ubuntu 22.04 don't run :).
I tried with boot-repair from live cd with no success.
Is it possible to fix this without reinstalling ubuntu?
Thank you.

Here is the report of boot repair, I don't know if it will be useful:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k9ZC87Z3MN/

Comment: Your question actually confuses me; I gather you're on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which has the default python3 version of 3.10; but you changed it to 3.10??  (`3.10.4-0ubuntu2` is the initial version found on *original* 22.04 media; being later for 22.04.1 etc).  You didn't state if you're using Ubuntu Desktop (or Ubuntu Server) but the Desktop systems are very reliant on `python3` being default. Text terminal features should still work though to revert your changes, but you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without loss of files/data if you don't format (ensure you have good backups anyway).

Comment: @user535733 Yes, finally I destroyed it :). This command saved me: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @guiverc I was confused, too. I have python 3.7 in /usr/local/bin and python 3.7, 3.10, 3.11 in /usr/bin on Ubuntu Desktop. When I start python3 from terminal it runs 3.7. I wanted to have easy way to switch versions in terminal. I tried with update-alternatives and give privelige to 3.10. I saw that Livepatch crashed but ignored it, then I logged out and this was the end.